# Which mimeType to choose for a generic file in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, mime

I am working on an Android application that needs to request files of any kind to others. For this reason, I am using a code like the following, as per Android documentation:

```
mRequestFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
mRequestFileIntent.setType(genericMimeType);
startActivityForResult(mRequestFileIntent, 0);
```

At the beginning I had `genericMimeType = "*/*"`, but the problem with this approach is that we can also get results with mime type `vnd.android.cursor.item/contact`, so a cursor.
Is there an easy way to limit the mime type only to files, that for example can be sent as attachments in an email?

Comment: You do not use `ACTION_PICK` with a MIME type. Use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `*/*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A generic mime-type would be :

```
application/octet-stream
```